# String Formatting with money

Tags: java, file, split, string-formatting, stringtokenizer

I am trying to write a program that receives an input and output file with a list of coins and the amount of those coins.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CookieJar {
public static void cashingIn(File input, File output){
    try{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
        PrintWriter writ = new PrintWriter(output);
        double sum = 0;
        if(in.hasNext()){
        String next = in.nextLine();
        Scanner help = new Scanner(next);
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            int y = Integer.parseInt(next.substring(0, 1));
            if(next.contains("pennies")){
                sum += y*0.01;
            }
            if(next.contains("dimes")){
                sum += y*.1;
            }
            if(next.contains("quarters")){
                sum += y*.25;
            }
            if(next.contains("nickles")){
                sum += y*.05;
            }
            if(next.contains("penny")){
                sum += .01;
            }
            if(next.contains("dime")){
                sum += .1;
            }
            if(next.contains("nickle")){
                sum += .05;
            }
            if(next.contains("quarter")){
                sum += .25;
            }
            if(sum == 0){
                String find = String.format("%s", "You have no money in the jar");
                writ.println(find);
            }
            String fixer = String.format("$%sf", sum);
            writ.println("You have " + fixer + " in the jar");
        }
        help.close();
        }
        else{
            String find = String.format("%s" , "You have no money in the jar");
            writ.println(find);
        }
            in.close();

            writ.close();
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
 }
}
```

The problem I am having with this code is that I am having trouble getting the amount of coins from the file and make sure what type of each coin it is. Here is an example of a tester method I am using.

```
@Test
public void test3() {
    try {
        // create file
        File        input  = folder.newFile( "input.txt" );
        File        output = folder.newFile( "output.txt" );

        PrintWriter write  = new PrintWriter( input );
        write.println( "32 nickels" );
        write.println( " 1" );
        write.println( "   nickel 42" );
        write.println( "quarters 1 penny" );
        write.println( "1 quarter 23 pennies 16" );
        write.println( "" );
        write.println( "dimes 1 dime 1 dime 1 dime 1 dime" );
        write.close();

        // invoke program
        CookieJar.cashingIn( input, output );

        // verify file results
        assertTrue  ( "Output file does not exist", output.exists() );
        Scanner scan     = new Scanner( output );
        String  expected = "You have $14.64 in the jar";
        assertTrue  ( "Unexpected end of file: expected \"%s\"" + expected, scan.hasNext() );
        String  actual   = scan.nextLine();
        assertEquals( "Incorrect result", expected, actual );
        assertFalse ( "File contains more data than expected", scan.hasNext() );
        scan.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        fail( "No exception should be thrown" );
    }
}
```

I also have to make the number have commas if I go into the thousands. I probably am not being specific enough with what is needed to help me so if you need more clarification just ask. Thank you for any of your help. I am so confused with formmating.

Comment: Don't use a `double` to represent money, it can't represent all values exactly (for example, `0.1` can't be represented). Use a `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: "The problem I am having with this code is that I am having trouble getting" maybe you could be more specific? The issue might be that you are using a strange substring

Comment: A line which contains "quarters" also contains "quarter", so you will double-count all amounts (except penny)

Comment: You're only checking the next string once, so when you have the line 

write.println( "dimes 1 dime 1 dime 1 dime 1 dime" );

Come up in your test code, it will run the following if blocks once:

if(next.contains("dimes")){
                sum += y*.1;
            }

if(next.contains("dime")){
                sum += .1;
            }

But I'm guessing you need to count it for each time the strings appear.

You're also assuming the number is only ever found in the first character of the string:
int y = Integer.parseInt(next.substring(0, 1));

When that is clearly not the case

Comment: As @AndyTurner suggested you will double count most plural quantities, as *quarter* is in *quarters*, *dime* in *dimes*, etc. **More importantly however** you allow only 1 digit at the beginning of each line by using `int y = Integer.parseInt(next.substring(0, 1));`. Your test data seems to contradict that assumption.

Comment: @Draken but also OP isn't considering when the quantity appears on the line before the unit, e.g. "1" and "nickel" in the example.

Comment: @Keppil you don't need to use BigDecimal - just use an int, counting in pennies.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Sure, that works too. Personally I like `BigDecimal` better, but I guess it is just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

*This is kind of an extended comment, but following this will help you solve the problem yourself I believe.*

It's good that you have a test, but it and the code are testing/doing too much. Processing strings and counting coins are at least one responsibility, and interacting with files is definitely a whole other responsibility. By testing both at once, your tests will be complicated and slow.

Applying the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) makes it easier and faster to test:

```
//The ONLY responsibility of this class is to keep count of coin strings it is given
public class CookieJar {
   private double sum = 0; //consider internally counting pennies with an int

   public void addString(string next){
      int y = Integer.parseInt(next.substring(0, 1));
      if(next.contains("pennies")){
          sum += y*0.01;
      }
      //etc (but no code that reads/writes to console or files)
   }

   public string summarize(){
      if(sum == 0){
         return String.format("%s", "You have no money in the jar");
      }
      String fixer = String.format("$%sf", sum);
      return "You have " + fixer + " in the jar";
   }
}
```

The tests will be so much easier to write and faster, you can easily test each coin type individually in separate tests, and then test all together when they all work:

```
@Test
public void test3() {
    CookieJar cookieJar = new CookieJar();

    cookieJar.addString("32 nickels");

    assertEquals("You have $1.60 in the jar", cookieJar.summarize());
}
```

The from file code now looks simpler:

```
//The ONLY responsibility of this class is to allow reading and writing of coin files 
public final class CookieJarIo {

    private CookieJarIo(){} //static class

    public static void cashingIn(File input, File output){
        try{
            Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
            PrintWriter writ = new PrintWriter(output);

            CookieJar cookieJar = new CookieJar(); //use our other class

            if (in.hasNext()){
              String next = in.nextLine();
              Scanner help = new Scanner(next);
              while(in.hasNextLine()){
                cookieJar.addString(next);
                writ.println(cookieJar.summarize());
              }
              help.close();
            } else {
                writ.println(cookieJar.summarize());
            }
            in.close();

            writ.close();
        } catch(IOException e){

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give strong consideration to @weston's answer about separating responsibilities.

However, in this code, you can make it work if you note that you expect the input file to contain a stream alternating an integer and a string, e.g.

```
32 nickels
 1
nickel 42
quarters 1 penny
1 quarter 23 pennies 16

dimes 1 dime 1 dime 1 dime 1 dime
```

You can detect and process tokens in this pattern with `Scanner in`:

```
int amountInPennies = 0;
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
  int quantity = in.nextInt();

  if (!in.hasNext()) {
    System.err.println("Didn't have a unit! Stopping.");
    break;
  }
  String unit = in.next();

  switch (unit) {
    case "penny":
    case "pennies":
      amountInPennies += 1 * quantity;
      break;
    case "nickel":
    case "nickels":
      amountInPennies += 5 * quantity;
      break;
    // etc.
  }
}
BigDecimal amountInDollars = BigDecimal.valueOf(amountInPennies, -2);
System.out.println("You have " + amount + " in the jar.");
```

In terms of how to format the amount as a currency, you should look into [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance())